# How to fix a cell width in a table where width = 100%

Tags: html, width, cell, css-tables

I would like to know if it's possible, in a table where width=100%, and where each column width are % value, to get for the last column a fixed width?

If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer would be no, not with CSS in a simple way. It is quite troublesome to mix fixed and relative width for obvious reasons.

There is however a new CSS3 feature [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/calc) that can be used to let the browser calculate the proper width.

**Notice** Unfortunately it is still just experimental, and has  limited browser support.

Comment: Thanks, 
That's what i've thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using CSS:

```
#mytable td:last-child {
  width: 50px; /* change to whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: That would give the last column a fixed width, but it won't work if the rest of the table has relative widths right? I believe that is what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If your site requires JavaScript anyway, you could manipulate the width after rendering.

1. Let the browser render your table with relative column widths close to an ideal but without setting the last one to be fixed.
2. Read the width of the rendered table.
3. Subtract the width you would like the last column to have from the table width.
4. Calculate the width for the remaining columns by percentage using the value from 3. as 100%
5. Set all column widths programatically

Comment: Thanks, 
I found another solution, without using javascript ;)

Comment: @ThomaBigueres, please update your question with the solution you found or post an answer yourself. It might help others in the future.